# Can geom_smooth accept logical variables for glm?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have a tibble with numerical and logical variables, e.g. like this:

```
       x     f      y
   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1 -2        1 -0.801
 2 -1.96     0 -2.27 
 3 -1.92     0 -1.75 
 4 -1.88     0 -2.44 
 5 -1.84     1 -0.123
          ...
```

For reproducibility, it can be generated using:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)
tb1 = tibble(
  x=(-50:50)/25,
  p=plogis(x),
  f=rbinom(p, 1, p),
  y = x+f+rnorm(x, 0, .5)
) %>% select(-p)
```

I'd like to plot the points and draw regression lines, once taking `x` as the predictor and `f` as the outcome (logistic regression), and once taking `x` and `f` as predictors and `y` as the outcome (linear regression). This works well for the logistic regression.

```
ggplot(tb1, aes(x, f)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"))
```

produces:

[image: Logistic regression, successful]

but:

```
ggplot(tb1, aes(x, y, colour=f)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

produces:

[image: Linear regression, wrong]

which is wrong. I want `f` treated as a factor, producing two regression lines, and a discrete instead of the continuous-coloured legend. I can force `f` manually to a logical value:

```
tb2 = tb1 %>% mutate(f = f>0)
```

and obtain the correct linear regression graph:

[image: Linear regression, correct]

but now I cannot plot the logistic regression. I get the

> Warning message:
>   Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
>   y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

For some reason, both `lm()` and `glm()` have no problems:

```
summary(glm(f ~ x, binomial, tb1))
summary(lm(y ~ x + f, tb1))
summary(glm(f ~ x, binomial, tb2))
summary(lm(y ~ x + f, tb2))
```

all produce reasonable results, and the results are identical for `tb1` and `tb2`, as they should be. So is there a way of convincing `geom_smooth` to accept logical variables, or must I use two redundant variables, with identical values but of a different type, e.g. `f.int` and `f.lgl`?

Comment: How about just using `colour = (f>0)` or `colour = factor(f)` in your `ggplot`?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, this is a workaround, but it would give me a legend "f>0" instead of simply "f". However, semantically, `f` is a logical variable and I would like to treat it such in the rest of the code. The opposite workaround would be to use `1*f` as the predictor in the logistic plot, but it all makes the code less readable.

Comment: You can easily use the `name` argument in a `scale_colour` statement to change the name of the variable in the legend.  The problem is that `ggplot` tends to treat anything numeric as a continuous variable.  If `f` is logical, I'd have thought you could just use `y=f` directly in the logistic plot - it will be coerced to numeric.

Comment: @Andrew: I would have also thought that logicals are automatically coerced to numeric. `glm` seems to be capable of it, but not `ggplot`. As for `scale_colour`, thanks, but it is still looks like a workaround, not much differernt from using two variables of a different type.

Comment: what's the problem of converting f to logical (you can also use `as.logical(f)`) for to use within color aesthetic as suggested by @AndrewGustar? That's not really a workaround, but just adapting the variable class to the needs of the functions. That should also not really be a problem in the script?

Comment: About your question with summary(glm(f ~ x, binomial, tb2)); there is no problem with regressing factors. However, if you look at ggplot(tb1, aes(x, f)), your y-axis is declared as a factor, so whatever comes out of your predict.. is not going to fit in

Comment: like suggested by @AndrewGustar, you either convert f to logical in the lm plot, or you do ggplot(tb2, aes(x, as.numeric(f))) + ... , which gives you the same problem right?